# cannot import ngx-gauge to Razor Pages

Tags: c#, npm, razor-pages

i cannot include ngx-gauge component to my Razor Pages application. Dont know why, but it didnt shows after installing npm package. Any ideas why it is not working? This is example from dev tool. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-gauge

```
<ngx-gauge [type]="gaugeType"
           [value]="gaugeValue"
           [label]="gaugeLabel"
           [append]="gaugeAppendText">
</ngx-gauge>
```

Comment: Try to refer to `Angular Version Compatibility Table` in your link,`ngx-gauge` is used for angular,not razor  page.

Comment: Hello, do you know how to do it? It is even possible to refer?